# Azure Blob storage append blob 409 / modified error when refreshing portal / storage explorer whilst appending

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I am receiving an error whilst uploading chunks to an append blob in Azure. Left alone, the process works ok but the problem arises the moment I refresh the container with Storage explorer (latest version) or refresh the page in the Azure portal whilst its uploading. My process throws the following.

```
An exception of type 'Azure.RequestFailedException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll but was not handled in user code: 'The blob has been modified while being read.
RequestId:62778adb-001e-011e-29a4-d589bf000000
Time:2021-11-09T20:02:29.3183234Z
Status: 409 (The blob has been modified while being read.)
ErrorCode: BlobModifiedWhileReading
```

Taking a lease out on the file makes no difference.

Test code is

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Buffers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using System.Text;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized;

namespace str
{
    static class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string ContainerName = "files";
            const string BlobName = "my.blob";
            const int ChunkSize = 4194304; // 4MB

            const string connstr = "some-connecting-string-to-your-datalake-gen-2-account";
            
            BlobServiceClient blobClient = new(connstr);

            BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobClient.GetBlobContainerClient(ContainerName);
            await containerClient.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

            AppendBlobClient appendClient = containerClient.GetAppendBlobClient(BlobName);
            await appendClient.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

            using FileStream fs = await FileMaker.CreateNonsenseFileAsync();
            using BinaryReader reader = new(fs);

            bool readLoop = true;

            while (readLoop)
            {
                byte[] chunk = reader.ReadBytes(ChunkSize);

                if (chunk.Length > 0)
                    await appendClient.AppendBlockAsync(new MemoryStream(chunk));

                readLoop = chunk.Length == ChunkSize;
            }

            fs.Close();
            File.Delete(fs.Name);
        }
    }

    public static class FileMaker
    {
        public static async Task<FileStream> CreateNonsenseFileAsync(int blocks = 30000)
        {
            string tempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
            FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite(tempFile);
            byte[] buffer = ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Rent(1024);

            Random randy = new();

            using (StreamWriter writer = new(fs))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < blocks; i++)
                {
                    randy.NextBytes(buffer);
                    await writer.WriteAsync(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer));
                }
            }

            return File.OpenRead(tempFile);
        }
    }
}
```

csproj is

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Files.DataLake" Version="12.8.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Buffers" Version="4.5.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I can only imagine the act of refreshing the page somehow triggers a metadata change and the service gives up enthusiastically but seems fairly arbitrary as you may not know who is poking about in blob storage as you are uploading to it?

As above, left alone with no one refreshing the page in the portal or storage explorer this code works fine and uploads the garbage in 4MB chunks (limit of append blob writes, switching to 2MB chunks doesn't make a difference) without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the scenario in my system not facing the issue that you are facing. Able to get the appended data after the refresh the portal .

[image]

**OUTPUT**

Before refresh the blob

[image]

After refresh the blob

[image]

[image]

Comment: Getting the data is fine, it's if I refresh whilst it's appending blocks I get the exception.

Comment: Can you please explain little bit more how you refreshing in azure portal?

Comment: Just clicking the refresh button above the list of blobs, same as in storage explorer. Not a full page reload.

Comment: same I did able to get the appended blob  refer the screen shot in above answer .can you please try once again  and  Sign out from azure portal and Sign in  azure portal again check once, Still facing any  issue let me know

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with downloading the blob. Whilst you are uploading click refresh in the portal, this throws an exception in the uploading code. It has to be uploading when you click refresh.

Comment: while appending  to the blob ,same time you are refreshing blob in portal ,Correct me if I
 am wrong, Same  I  did .

Comment: If the answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Comment: This happens not when appending a block like in the posters code, but when using a stream to write to the appendblob. I get the same error as OP if i refresh the portal while writing to the AppendBlob stream using `OpenWrite()`